# Bash dialog - checklist options with spaces from a file

Tags: bash, parameters, dialog, escaping

I try to make a dialog checklist in a bash script. I have to generate options from lines of a file. I think the problem is that my entries contains spaces and so, one entry is considered by many.

Dialog give me this error:

```
Error: Expected 3 arguments, found only 1. Use --help to list options.
```

Here my code:

```
while read entry; do
    option+=(0 "$entry" "off")
    echo "$option"
done < "$tempfilelist"

dialog --backtitle "Myscript"  \
       --title "Mytitle" \
       --checklist "Mytext" 10 70 4 "${option[@]}"
```

I even tried to put quotes in my loop, like this:

```
"'$entry'"
```

but no change.

and here's my file (tempfilelist):

```
Wed Apr 24 14:17:20 2013 20130423.maya.txt
Wed Apr 24 14:17:41 2013 maya.txt
```

How to get this script working?

Thanks !

Comment: I do ./my_script.sh. I don't know why you want arguments. I don't need them. They come from the file (tempfilelist)

Comment: The code posted above works for me, with `/bin/sh` linked to `bash` 3.2.48.

Comment: @chepner : how did you make it works? Which is your version of dialog?

Comment: I have dialog 1.1-20120215. One thought: are you sure `option` is being populated? If it is empty, `"${options[@]}"` will expand to a single empty string.

Comment: Yeah, option is not empty. The problem, I think, are spaces in my string.
args[0]="0" 
args[1]="Wed"
args[2]="Apr"
args[3]="24"
...
How to deal with?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same code you posted here? The code here has no variable named `args`, and it works fine for me. Everything above is quoted correctly to handle strings containing spaces.

Comment: Yeah I run the same code, args were just here to show my vision of: "How dialog see my parameters". Sorry if I can't explain well. I ran this code separately in another script, and I have another error: `./test.sh: 3: ./test.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")` at `option+=(0 "$entry" "off")`
`.
Don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is not being run by `bash`; it's being run by `dash`. Change the first line of your script from

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Yes I was `#!/bin/sh`. I changed it by `#!/usr/bin/env bash` Thank you very much !